# how to get list data in sharepoint 2010 using csom

Tags: list

I want to get specific fields data in list from sharepoint 2010 site using csom
can someone me help with code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you leveraging the managed CSOM (C#/VB) or the JavaScript CSOM (also called JSOM)?

Comment: managed CSOM (C#)

Comment: More than anything, a bit of Googling would have helped you.

Comment: Yes Sane.Amit 
i did that and tried the code with the same but not able to figure out the requirement as i need.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Provide the second parameter in [ClientRuntimeContext.Load method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/jj171831(v=office.15).aspx) in order to specify *the list of the properties to retrieve from the server*, for example:

```
ctx.Load(listItems, icol => icol.Include(i => i["<field name>"]));
```

The following example demonstrates how to load `Title` and `Status` properties only for task items:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
     //ctx.Credentials = credentials;

     var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Tasks");  //get List 
     var listItems = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery()); //get all List Items
     ctx.Load(listItems, icol => icol.Include(i => i["Title"], i => i["Status"])); //specify what List Items properties to load  
     ctx.ExecuteQuery(); // submit query to the server

     //print results
     foreach (var listItem in listItems)
     {
           Console.WriteLine("Task details(Title: {0}, Status: {1})", listItem["Title"], listItem["Status"]);
     }
}
```

Comment: I am getting error in the below line showing red line at icol => icol.Include(i => i["Title"], i => i["Status"]));

Comment: Please try to copy/paste the whole example that I have provided and then modify it..

Comment: Thanks i will try with that
meanwhile can you also tell me that how to get the data from the folder which is inside the list

Comment: clientContext.Load(
                collListItem,
                items => items.Take(5).Include(
                item => item["Employee Name"],
                item => item["Display Status"]));

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Title: {0} \nBody: {1}\n", oListItem["Employee Name"], oListItem["Display Status"]);}} }}

Comment: getting error for the above code as "Additional information: Column 'Employee Name' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user."

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code:

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SiteUrl"); 

// Assume the web has a list named "Announcements". 
List announcementsList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements"); 

// This creates a CamlQuery that has a RowLimit of 100, and also specifies Scope="RecursiveAll" 
// so that it grabs all list items, regardless of the folder they are in. 
CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100); 
ListItemCollection items = announcementsList.GetItems(query); 

// Retrieve all items in the ListItemCollection from List.GetItems(Query). 
context.Load(items); 
context.ExecuteQuery(); 
foreach (ListItem listItem in items) 
{ 
    // We have all the list item data. For example, Title. 
    label1.Text = label1.Text + ", " + listItem["Title"]; 
}
```

Comment: i have tried it
let me say a scenario
i have a list name"xyz" having six fields A,B,C,D,E,F
if i want to get the data of only A coloumn then how to write

Comment: whats the scenario?

Comment: You can specify `ViewFields` in a CAML query. The syntax for doing so depends on which CSOM you are using (managed or client-side). In your example, you'd set only field A as a view field. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798388.aspx.

Comment: I am really a beginner. Can you provide some link or a piece of code

Comment: You use this for any field? which code are you using